# Are there free software options to view dgn files?

Tags: software-recommendations, dgn

I need to view a large number of .dgn files without adding it to ArcMap, Microstation. So I need a free software solution to view the dgn files. I will only be viewing the files and will not need to edit them. Can any one suggest one?

Comment: Do yo need to edit them?

Answer (score 1):

Microstation DGN is listed as a [GDAL driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_dgn.html) for reading. So you can use any tool for reading them that employs GDAL.

The most popular FOSS GIS doing just that would be [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/).